# Python bitmasking and point cluster/group of origin

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping, cluster-analysis, masking

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about creating a bit mask from a data set and sets of clusters using Python, such that each set of clusters will replace the index of the point in the original set.

For example:

```
data = [[10,10],[20,20],[5,3],[7,2],[90,78]] #Data of length 5
clusters = [[[10,10],[20,20]],[[5,3],[7,2],[90,78]]] #List containing two clusters (cluster 0 and cluster 1)

output = [0,0,1,1,1]
```

Basically, the output is supposed to show which cluster each point from the original data is in. I'm just now becoming familiar to the `map` function and figured I could make use of it, just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[10,10],[20,20],[5,3],[7,2],[90,78]] #Data of length 5
clusters = [[[10,10],[20,20]],[[5,3],[7,2],[90,78]]] #List containing two clusters (cluster 0 and cluster 1)

gen = (count for count, y in enumerate(clusters) for x in data if x in y)
output = list(gen)
```

Here is a generator expression that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the point pairs into a tuple instead of a list, allows us to use each point as a key in a dictionary (because the key must be hashable), with its cluster of origin as the value

```
data = [[10,10],[20,20],[5,3],[7,2],[90,78]]
clusters = [[[10,10], [20,20]], [[5,3], [7,2], [90,78]]]
cd = dict((tuple(p), i) for i, cl in enumerate(clusters) for p in cl)
output = [cd[tuple(p)] for p in data] # output = list(map(lambda p: cd[tuple(p)], data))
print(output)
```

produces

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

**PERFORMANCE**

Out of curiosity, I have compared my solution with @Back2Basics', to find out how well the two scale with a growing data population.

The following utility functions generate a data set of `N x N` points and partition it in clusters of equal size

```
def gen_data(n):
    return [[x, y] for x in range(n) for y in range(n)]

def gen_clusters(data, c_size):
    g = [iter(data)]*c_size
    return [list(c) for c in zip(*g)]
```

And these are the two solutions:

```
def ck_pynchia(data, clusters):
    cd = dict((tuple(p), i) for i, cl in enumerate(clusters) for p in cl)
    output = [cd[tuple(p)] for p in data]
    return output

def ck_b2b(data, clusters):
    gen = (count for count, y in enumerate(clusters) for x in data if x in y)
    output = list(gen)
    return output
```

Now let's time them

with a data set of 10*10 points

```
python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(10); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 10); cl.ck_pynchia(data,clusters)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.2 usec per loop

python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(10); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 10); cl.ck_b2b(data,clusters)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 330 usec per loop
```

with a data set of 50*50 points

```
python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(50); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 50); cl.ck_pynchia(data,clusters)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 msec per loop

python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(50); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 50); cl.ck_b2b(data,clusters)'
10 loops, best of 3: 177 msec per loop
```

with a data set of 100*100 points

```
python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(100); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 100); cl.ck_pynchia(data,clusters)'
100 loops, best of 3: 6.37 msec per loop

python3 -mtimeit 'import clusters as cl; data = cl.gen_data(100); clusters = cl.gen_clusters(data, 100); cl.ck_b2b(data,clusters)'
10 loops, best of 3: 2.82 sec per loop
```

As we can see, the computational complexity of the two algorithms is quite different.

Final note: if you could hold the points in a tuple instead of a list, things would be slightly simpler and quicker:

```
data = [(10,10),(20,20),(5,3),(7,2),(90,78)]
clusters = [[(10,10), (20,20)], [(5,3), (7,2), (90,78)]]

cd = dict((p,i) for i, cl in enumerate(clusters) for p in cl)
output = [cd[p] for p in data] # output = list(map(lambda p: cd[p], data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with comprehensions:

`[idx for d in data for (c, idx) in zip(clusters, range(len(clusters))) if d in c]`

If you insist on using the map function, you could do something like this:

```
list(
    map(lambda tup: tup.index(True), 
        map(lambda d: list(map(lambda c: d in c, clusters)), data)
    )
)
```

The inner map generates a list of lists: for each element in data there's a list of True or False values showing if it is contained in the corresponding cluster.

```
[[True, False], [True, False], [False, True], [False, True], [False, True]]
```

The outer map gives the index of the first occurrence of True in the inner lists, which happens to be the index of the cluster of that data element.

Comment: interesting way of rewriting `enumerate` :). BTW, I think your solution mimics @Back2Basics'